# Programming error django postgresql on EC2 and RDS

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am hosting a server with EC2 and postgresql on RDS.

I am getting the following error when I try to log into my admin panel

ProgrammingError at /admin/

relation "django_admin_log" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "django_ad...

I am not able to use python manage.py syndb as the database is hosted on RDS.

For my local instance of the server, it got solved with

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23297

Comment: Are you sure you cannot use 'python manage.py syncdb' with RDS PostgreSQL? What problems are you seeing?

Comment: if Django can connect to your db you will be able to run `python manage.py syndb` ...you would do that from the EC2 instance